# How do I write an echo program in C?

Tags: c

the output should be something like this:

```
Enter Character : a
Echo : a
```

I wrote

```
int c;
  while (c != EOF)
    {
      printf("\n Enter input: ");
      c = getchar();
      putchar(c);
    }
```

But I get two Enter Input after the echos.

Comment: Do you want to echo only a character or the entire line? The echo program echoes the entire line though. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echo_%28command%29

Comment: @ArunSaha: I doubt the OP want means the `echo` command. `echo` prints its arguments, not standard input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two characters are retrieved during input. You need to throw away the carriage return.

```
int c = 0; 
int cr;
  while (c != EOF) 
    { 
      printf("\n Enter input: "); 
      c = getchar(); 
      cr = getchar();  /* Read and discard the carriage return */
      putchar(c); 
    }
```

Comment: Your `c` is not initialized. It can can have the value of `EOF` to start with.

Comment: @codaddict - You're right. I just copied the OP's code. I'll fix it.

Comment: What if the user enters two characters before pressing Enter?

Answer (score 2):

Homework?

If so, I won't give a complete answer/ You've probably got buffered input - the user needs to enter return before anything is handed back to your program. You need to find out how to turn this off.

(this is dependent on the environment of your program - if you could give more details of platform and how you are running the program, we could give better answers)

Answer (score 1):

take fgets eg:

```
char c[2];
if( fgets( c, 2, stdin ) )
  putchar( *c );
else
  puts("EOF");
```

and you dont have any problems with getchar/scanf(%c)/'\n' and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `scanf` instead?

Example:

```
char str[50];

printf("\n Enter input: ");
scanf("%[^\n]+", str);

printf(" Echo : %s", str);

return 0;
```

Outputs

```
 
 Enter input: xx
 Echo : xx
```

[scanf reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/scanf/)

Comment: You should also limit scanf input to 49 chars, otherwise you may risk a buffer overrun.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

main(){
    int number;
    char delimiter;
    printf("enter a line of positive integers\n");
    scanf("%d%c", &number, &delimiter);
    while(delimiter!='\n'){
        printf("%d", number);
        scanf("%d%c", &number, &delimiter);
    }
    printf("\n");
    getch();
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.